# Trying to understand to equal sums.

Tags: summation

Why is it that?

$$z + \sum_{2 \le k \le n}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n-1}}{n-1} k(k-1)p^{n-k} \dbinom{2n-k-2}{n-2}z^n = \sum_{j, k \ge 0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{j+k-1}}{j+k-1} k(k-1)p^j \dbinom{2j+k-2}{j}z^{j+k}. $$

I get that you can just plug $j+k=n$, but where does the $z$ appears in the latter?

Comment: Note that the sum on the left was over $k$, the one in the right is over $j$ and $k$? Also the binomial coefficient is not obtained just by substitution of$ j+k=n$. It may help if you tell about where does this come from (what context), what does it represent?

Comment: The first has index $k\ge 2$.  The second allows $k=0,1$.  I'd assume fo k=1 the term is z.  At least that what I assume just by skimming.

Comment: Page number 3. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2322567?seq=3#metadata_info_tab_contents

Answer (score 1):

> We start with the right-hand side and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j,k\geq 0}}&\color{blue}{\frac{q^{j+k-1}}{j+k-1}k(k-1)p^j\binom{2j+k-2}{j}z^{j+k}}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{j+k=n}\atop{j,k\geq 0}}\frac{q^{j+k-1}}{j+k-1}k(k-1)p^j\binom{2j+k-2}{j}\right)z^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{q^{n-1}}{n-1}k(k-1)p^{n-k}\binom{2n-k-2}{n-k}z^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq k\leq n\leq \infty}\frac{q^{n-1}}{n-1}k(k-1)p^{n-k}\binom{2n-k-2}{n-2}z^n\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=z+\sum_{2\leq k\leq n\leq \infty}\frac{q^{n-1}}{n-1}k(k-1)p^{n-k}\binom{2n-k-2}{n-2}z^n}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we reorder the summands by introducing $n=j+k, n\geq 0$.
- In (2) we eliminate the index $j$ by substituting $j=n-k$.
- In (3) we rewrite the index region and use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (4) we observe that the summands with indices $(n,k)\in\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$ vanish due to the factor $k(k-1)$, whereas in the case $(n,k)=(1,1)$ the expression $\frac{k-1}{n-1}$ cancels, leaving $z$.